# Outlook 2010 adds link underlines in signature

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

When I sent emails and include signature, Outlook adds blue underlines under each link in the signature. Is there any way around it?

I have tried everything with my Outlook 2010 signature. I coded simple html code with `text-decoration: none;` and even tried adding `!important`.

Answer (score -1):

give `text-decoration: none !important;` to `a` tag.

or you can do like this.

```
<style type="text/css">
        a {text-decoration: none !important; color: #000; cursor: text;}
       </style>
```

**OR**

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="mylink" style="text-decoration:none !important; color: #000000">Your Link</a></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```